# How to update multiple data for approval of user in the System in VB.net and MySql

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am trying to update the data in multiple way using checkbox in listview

for each item that is check in the listview it must be updated

this is my code

```
 Private Sub btn_approve_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_approve.Click
        Try


            For Each item As Object In ListView1.CheckedItems
                Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("UPDATE tbl_login SET tbl_logincnt = @tbl_logincnt WHERE tbl_loginid = '" & ListView1.SelectedItems(0).Text & "' ", con)

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tbl_logincnt", 1)


                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    MsgBox("Approve Successfully1")
                End Using
            Next


        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try

    End Sub
```

Comment: So what's the actual problem? What does that code do that you don't expect or not do that you do expect?

Comment: invalid index error sir

Comment: I want to update the data from mysql database  with the datable tbl_login in coloum tbl_logincnt from 0 to 1

Comment: but in multiple way using checkbox in listview

Comment: No one should have to read the comments to understand the question. Edit your question and add ALL the relevant information that should have been there in the first place.

Comment: Ther's a lot wrong there. Apart from the specific issue I've addressed in my answer below, you should change the stricture of your code. You should create one command object and add two parameters to it for the two variable values. In the loop, you would then just set the `Value` of each parameter and execute the command.

Answer (score 0):

You have this:

```vb
For Each item As Object In ListView1.CheckedItems
```

and yet you never use `item` any where in the loop. Instead, you use `ListView1.SelectedItems(0)`. How does that make sense? This tells me that you haven't actually done any debugging. If you had debugged the code then you would have looked at the value of `ListView1.SelectedItems(0).Text` and seen that it was obviously not what you were looking for. It should even have taken any debugging even, because if you had actually thought through the logic you needed to use and then compared that to the code you had, you'd have seen the obvious difference. These are the things that you need to do for yourself before pasting a question here.

Comment: Thank you. I got it now, what i did is I had use For Loop with the datatype of integer

Comment: @jonathanlabajo, why would you do that? You would only use an `Integer` as an index to get the item but you already had the item from your `For Each` statement. I already told you what the problem was: you were using `ListView1.SelectedItems(0)` instead of `item`. If you had actually got it you would have just changed that.

Comment: yes sir, I have change my code sir..from For Each Loop to For Loop. Thank you so much sir

Comment: If you used my answer, please accept it. If you didn't, please add your own answer and accept that. All questions should have an accepted answer if the issue has been resolved, so everyone can see that you don't need more help without opening the question. It also helps others who have the same issue.